# Pandas Matplotlib Line Graph

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, pivot-table

Given the following data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'YYYYMM':[201603,201503,201403,201303,201603,201503,201403,201303],
         'Count':[5,6,2,7,4,7,8,9],
         'Group':['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B']})
df

   Count    Group   YYYYMM
0   5         A     201603
1   6         A     201503
2   2         A     201403
3   7         A     201303
4   4         B     201603
5   7         B     201503
6   8         B     201403
7   9         B     201303
```

I need to generate a line graph with one line per group with a summary table at the bottom. Something like this:
[image]

I need each instance of 'YYYYMM' to be treated like a year by Pandas/Matplotlib.
So far, this seems to help, but I'm not sure if it will do the trick:

```
df['YYYYMM']=df['YYYYMM'].astype(str).str[:-2].astype(np.int64)
```

Then, I did this to pivot the data:

```
t=df.pivot_table(df,index=['YYYYMM'],columns=['Group'],aggfunc=np.sum)

    Count
Group   A   B
YYYYMM      
2013    7   9
2014    2   8
2015    6   7
2016    5   4
```

Then, I tried to plot it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
t.plot(table=t,ax=ax)
```

...and this happened:

[image]

I'd like to do the following:

1. remove all lines (borders) from the table at the bottom
2. remove the jumbled text in the table
3. remove the x axis tick labels (it should just show the years for tick labels)

I can clean up the rest myself (remove legend and borders, etc..).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I may not have fully understood what you mean by 1., since you are showing the table lines in your reference. I have also not understood whether you want to transpose the table.

What you may be looking for is:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'YYYYMM':[201603,201503,201403,201303,201603,201503,201403,201303],
     'Count':[5,6,2,7,4,7,8,9],
     'Group':['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B']})

df['YYYYMM']=df['YYYYMM'].astype(str).str[:-2].astype(int)

t=pd.pivot_table(df, values='Count', index='YYYYMM',columns='Group',aggfunc=np.sum)
t.index.name = None

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
t.plot(table=t,ax=ax)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.NullFormatter())

plt.tick_params(
    axis='x',          # changes apply to the x-axis
    which='both',      # both major and minor ticks are affected
    bottom='off',      # ticks along the bottom edge are off
    top='off',         # ticks along the top edge are off
    labelbottom='off') # labels along the bottom edge are off
plt.show()
```

[image]